# Create a remote directory c# using full control permissions. UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to Path Denied even using security rules

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, console-application

Hope you are well!

Thanks for reading my issue.

I´m trying to create a remote directory using spcefic credentials as Administrator, and also I checked Full Control Premission on the root directory in the seurity tab.

I'm running the program as the Administrator.

This Exception occurs when I try to create a Direcotry / Subdirectories.
But, when I create a File, it really works! (only when the path exists).
Using [File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes_array);].

If the path doesn´t exist the Exception occurs too.

As an aside, I'm using PinvokeWindowsNetworking Class: http://lookfwd.doitforme.gr/blog/media/PinvokeWindowsNetworking.cs

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Specify the directory you want to manipulate.

        try
        {
            PinvokeWindowsNetworking.connectToRemote(@"\\PC-NAME\MyDocuments", "Administrator", "MyPa$$");
            string path = @"R:\Recursos\ControlDocumentos\DIR\DIR1";
            string sRutaDestinoNva = path.Replace(@"R:", @"\\PC-NAME\MyDocuments");                

            DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
            securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"\Administrator", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

            if (Directory.Exists(sRutaDestinoNva))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Path is already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(sRutaDestinoNva, securityRules);
                Console.WriteLine("Directory and Subdirectories were creted succesfully: " + Directory.GetCreationTime(sRutaDestinoNva).ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        finally { PinvokeWindowsNetworking.disconnectRemote("\\\\PC-NAME\MyDocuments"); }
    }
```

[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc4EI.jpg)

I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Your code looks solid. two things: make sure you're running the program as the administrator - that's a must otherwise it will always fail. Two: have you looked into impersonation? you can, in code, run a part of your process as a different user than the one who started it. Also know that creating directories and subdirectories are by themselves a permission that your user account has to have - click the advanced button in the security tab of the file properties and you'll see it there.

Comment: Thanks @RichardBarker for your answer. One: I did it. Two: I want to run the process as the Administratro because it has the privileges and permissions.

Comment: System Admin will always have those perms. if you know your admin password then look into impersonation and impersonate the admin in your code. that way it wont matter what user you start it under, it will always run as the admin.